# Error in parsing Aramex WSDL file

Tags: java, web, service, wsdl, aramex

When I'm trying to parse the [Aramex shipping services WSDL](http://www.aramex.com/developers/aramex-apis/42194/Shipping-Services-API) (which is needed to create shipments), a namespace error occurs with following error log:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin>wsimport.exe -keep -verbose D:\ATG\aramex\shipping-services-api-wsdl\shipping-services-api-wsdl.wsdl -d D:\ATG\aramex\java\
parsing WSDL...

[WARNING] src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'ser:guid'. It was detected that 'ser:guid' is in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/D:/ATG/aramex/shipping-services-api-wsdl/shipping-services-api-wsdl.wsdl#types?schema1'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'ser:guid'
needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:/D:/ATG/aramex/shipping-services-api-wsdl/shipping-services-api-wsdl.wsdl#types?schema1'.
  line 331 of file:/D:/ATG/aramex/shipping-services-api-wsdl/shipping-services-api-wsdl.wsdl#types?schema1

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 126 of file:/D:/ATG/aramex/shipping-services-api-wsdl/shipping-services-api-wsdl.wsdl

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 57 of file:/D:/ATG/aramex/shipping-services-api-wsdl/shipping-services-api-wsdl.wsdl
```

How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: i was able to resolve the warning by adding <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/> in to wsdl. But collisions are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i resolved it. I changed one declaration and after the it worked.